# Subtotal filtering without a group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a report with 5 groups in a Tablix. I want to have 15 total lines based on a filter of amounts within that group.  A simplified version:

```
Group1  Cost Center Relationship Type  Amount
A       100         Rel1         Small 100
A       100         Rel1         Med   100
A       100         Rel2         Small 200
Total for A Small:                     300
Total for A Medium:                    100
```

I cannot group on Type because I am ordering by Relationship.

I added 2 more group rows to make 3 (one for each Type). I used "Add total" to the existing group. I tried using an IIF(Fields!Type.value="Small",SUM(Fields!Amount.value),0) in the group row but all I get is zeroes. I am not sure if I need to specify a scope because it is in the group already.

Comment: are you want group rows in total area ?

Comment: I want to filter group totals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, IIF(Fields!Type.value="Small",SUM(Fields!Amount.value,0) wont work as it is.

You would need:

IIF(Fields!Type.value="Small",SUM(Fields!Amount.value),0)

Or try this:

SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.value="Small",Fields!Amount.value,0))

I forget in a GROUP footer if you need to SUM() inside the logic (top example) or SUM() the result of the logic (bottom example)

Comment: That was a typo.  The ,0 is outside the sum.  The IIF in the sum generates an #Error.  The IIF on the outside gives wrong results. I can't figure out why.

Comment: SSRS is case sensitive, are all of your "Small" just that?  Capital 'S' lowercase 'mall'?  Or is it mixed "small", "Small", "SMALL"  If so, try converting the results to a single type and compare correctly against that

Comment: Yes, I am matching the case.  I am getting results, but they don't make sense. I am getting the sum for Small when I used Medium as the criteria in some cases and no results in other cases.

Comment: I had to convert the value using CDBL and it worked.  Thanks